# How to fix error: "Null check operator used on a null value"?

Tags: json, flutter, class, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm getting a `Null check operator used on a null value` error in flutter.

```
Map<String, dynamic> newUserMap = jsonDecode(authenticate.body);
print('newUserMap?');
var authNodeUser = TokenContent.fromJson(newUserMap);
print('authNodeUser?');
String? jwtToken = authNodeUser.jwtToken;
print('jwtToken = ' + authNodeUser.jwtToken!);
```

as I'm seeing `newUserMap?` and `authNodeUser?` I'm guessing the error occurs here;

```
String? jwtToken = authNodeUser.jwtToken;
print('jwtToken = ' + authNodeUser.jwtToken!);
```

Here's the `TokenContent` class;

```
class TokenContent {
  int? currUser;
  String? jwtToken;
  String? refreshToken;

  TokenContent({this.currUser, this.jwtToken, this.refreshToken});

  TokenContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    currUser = json['currUser'];
    jwtToken = json['token'];
    refreshToken = json['refreshToken'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['currUser'] = this.currUser;
    data['jwtToken'] = this.jwtToken;
    data['refreshToken'] = this.refreshToken;
    return data;
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems 'jwtToken' has a null value by the time print('jwtToken = ' + authNodeUser.jwtToken!); statement executes.

Answer (score 0):

Print `newUserMap` and make sure `jwtToken` exist in the http response.